# Como pegar o numero do vetor do elemento que eu cliquei JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para pegar o numero do vetor de um img por exemplo? tá vendo ali na imagem vários img né? Quero algo em que no momento que eu clicar na imagem eu possa pegar o número desse img, alguma função,gambiarra sei lá pff

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Nunca use código na imagem copie cole

Comment: Fica impossivel eu fazer um efeito de ao passar rato em cima da imagem ela ficar escurinha cortando imagem. como faZ?

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer com [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  alert('O elemento encontra-se na posição ' +$(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
```

Se quiseres que uma determinada acção ocorra num determinado elemento baseada no seu index (posição dentro de um vector) podes fazer:

```js
$('div').eq(2).on('click', function() {
  alert('Clicou no elemento ' +$(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
```

Neste caso o evento click foi delegado apenas à terceira div.

Também podes usar [child seletores css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```js
$('div:nth-child(3)').on('click', function() {
    alert('Clicou no elemento ' +$(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
<div>Hey</div>
```

Comment: Obrigada Bjsssss